# Web scrape password protected website but there are errors

Tags: r, web-scraping, password-protection

I am trying to scrape data from the member directory of a website ("members.dublinchamber.ie"). I have tried using the 'rvest' but I got the data from the login page even after entering the login details. The code is as follows:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "members.dublinchamber.ie/login.aspx"
pgsession <- html_session(url)  
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[2]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                      "Username" = "username",
                      "Password" = "password")
submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
memberlist <-      jump_to(pgsession,'members.dublinchamber.ie/directory/profile.aspx?compid=50333')
page <- read_html(memberlist)
usernames <- html_nodes(x = page, css = 'css of required data')
data_usernames <- data.frame(html_text(usernames, trim =   TRUE),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I also used RCurl and again I'm getting data from the login page. The RCurl code is as follows:

```
library(RCurl)
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt', followlocation = TRUE, autoreferer = TRUE, curl = curl)
html <- getURL('http://members.dublinchamber.ie/login.aspx', curl = curl)
viewstate <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATE" value=['142555296'].*', '\\1', html))
params <- list(
  'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ExistingMembersLogin1$username'= 'username',
  'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ExistingMembersLogin1$password'= 'pass',
  'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ExistingMembersLogin1$btnSubmit'= 'login',
  '__VIEWSTATE'                         = viewstate
)
html = postForm('http://members.dublinchamber.ie/login.aspx', .params = params, curl = curl)
 grep('Logout', html)
```

There are 3 URL's actually:
1) members.dublinchamber.ie/directory/default.aspx(has the names of all industry and it is required to click on any industry)
2) members.dublinchamber.ie/directory/default.aspx?industryVal=AdvMarPubrel (the advmarpubrel is just a small string which is generated as i clicked that industry)
3) members.dublinchamber.ie/directory/profile.aspx?compid=19399 (this has the profile information of a specific company which i clicked in the previous page)

i want to scrape data which should give me industry name, list of companies in each industry and their details which are present as a table in the 3rd URL above.
I am new here and also to R, webscrape. Please don't mind if the question was lengthy or not that clear.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem where the change from login-page to content-page was being accomplished via javascript. To see if that's what's happening for you, try opening the page manually in a browser with javascript (and flash) completely disabled. If you get the same behavior, you're likely stuck. In which case, you might consider using [`RSelenium`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html).

Comment: I have checked the js. The viewstate and eventvaldiation get changed for all the three URL's which I have mentioned and I really am not able to understand about how I can connect the data from 3 URL's and output my data. The "Industryval" and "compid" keep changing for different industries and companies.

Comment: I also have a small doubt about entereing the value of viewstate after decoding it. which way is right? `value=[142555296]` or `value = ['142555296']` and the event validation is giving me an array of 4 elements when i tried to decode it using httpdebugger. How should I place those values. Please, help!!

Comment: Your assignment to `viewstate` does not work. I don't know what format `value` should take, it depends on the server/page implementation. My point about javascript-triggers is that the redirection may be done via javascript code, not by URL alone, in which case you'll need somehow to trigger the javascript code itself. I think your only option may be RSelenium. One good thing is that it works with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), a virtual browser that does js execution.

Comment: I have not done scraping using RSelenium. Is there any good source where I can find tips or code to scrape password protected website using RSelenium and PhantomJS??

Comment: The vignettes included in the package (and [found at CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RSelenium/)) do a good job, both the Basics and Headless vignettes specifically.